# leftMerge function to deep overlay saved state

Tags: javascript, array

This code is used to deep overlay saved state (as an object) over a template object, which is the current model, this model can change (e.g have new attributes added), and a simple _.clone call will not cut it since that does a shallow copy, and will copy nested arrays/objects byref. This code works, and I'm curious if you would you fail it on code review or have any suggestions to make it better?  Please don't be kind!

```
function isObjectPair(a, b) {
    return typeof a == 'object' && typeof b == 'object';
}

function isArrayPair(a, b) {
    return _.isArray(a) && _.isArray(b);
}

function isArrayOrObjectPair(a, b) {
    return isObjectPair || isArrayPair(a, b);
}

function leftMerge(a, b) {
    for (var i in b) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (isArrayPair(a[i],b[i])) {
                for (var j = 0, jlen = b[i].length; j < jlen; j++) {
                    if (isArrayOrObjectPair(a[i][j], b[i][j])) {
                        leftMerge(a[i][j], b[i][j]);
                    } else {
                        a[i][j] = b[i][j];
                    }
                }
            } else if (isObjectPair(a[i], b[i])) {
                if (a[i] === null) {
                    a[i] = _.clone(b[i]);
                } else {
                    leftMerge(a[i], b[i]);
                }
            } else {
                a[i] = b[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need deep copies all the way through, and `_.clone` makes shallow ones, isn't the line `a[i] = _.clone(b[i])` an error?  As for your general question, another approach (which may or may not work for you) is to use an existing deep copy solution, and deep copy `b` into a temp `c`.  Now iterate through `a`'s properties, and add them to `c`, but only if they don't already exist in `c`.  Finally, replace `a` with `c`.  This lets you leverage existing work on deep copying, which is a tricky but (I think) solved problem.